# WordPress cf7 multiple steps plugin in jQuery tab

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I am working on contact form 7 multiple steps in WordPress. I can set it up for different pages, it's an easy job for me and also there is a lot of help for that when searching the web.

The problem I am facing is I am using this multistep plugin in jQueryUI tabs and I have to move the control to the next tab when user user click on the button next step. Below is my HTML:

```
 <div id="tabs">
   <ul>
     <li><a href="#tabs-1">REGISTRATION QUESTIONS</a></li>
     <li><a href="#tabs-2">PATIENT INFO</a></li>
     <li><a href="#tabs-3">CONSENT</a></li>
   </ul>
   <div id="tabs-1">
     <p>[contact-form-7 id="335" title="User Multisteps Registration stp-1"]</p>
   </div>
   <div id="tabs-2">
     <p>[contact-form-7 id="338" title="User Multisteps Registration stp-2"]</p>
   </div>
   <div id="tabs-3">
     <p>agree form</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

In additional settings what should be the code?

```
on_sent_ok: code here
```

Comment: you will need to do this with jQuery, added the tag for you

Comment: any help or reference link please